# RosTutorials won't build on Raspberry Pi running Hydro

Tags: raspberrypi, rasbperrypi, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've installed hydro onto a raspberry pi having built the package following the instructions on the website. I've fetched the tutorials from github so I can run the turtlesim. The build keeps failing with the following error.  It's probably something fairly obvious...

<== Finished processing package [56 of 63]: 'rosnode'

==> Processing catkin package: 'rospy_tutorials'
==> Building with env: '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh'
==> cmake /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_tutorials/rospy_tutorials -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rospy_tutorials -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated in '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rospy_tutorials'
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rospy_tutorials
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated
-- This workspace overlays: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Python version: 2.7
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rospy_tutorials/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.86
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
CMake Error at /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rospy_tutorials/cmake/rospy_tutorials-genmsg.cmake:3 (message):
Could not find messages which
'/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_tutorials/rospy_tutorials/msg/HeaderString.msg'
depends on.  Did you forget to specify generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)?

Cannot locate message [Header] in package [std_msgs] with paths
[['/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/std_msgs/share/std_msgs/cmake/../msg']]
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/genmsg/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:298 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:9 (generate_messages)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
<== Failed to process package 'rospy_tutorials':
Command '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh cmake /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_tutorials/rospy_tutorials -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rospy_tutorials -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated' returned non-zero exit status 1

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/162821/rostutorials-won%27t-build-on-raspberry-pi-running-hydro/) by [Blueboater](https://answers.ros.org/users/17771/blueboater/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-05-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I ran into essentially this same issue while compiling ROS Indigo on Raspberry Pi as per [1]. In my case `/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/std_msgs/share/std_msgs` had no `msg` directory. I worked around it by:

```
cd /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/std_msgs/share/std_msgs
ln -s /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/std_msgs/msg
```

Not sure why the `msg` directory didn't get setup in the first place... or why the message search path doesn't just point to `src/std_msgs/msg`... or how to even configure the search path... but at least the error message was informative enough to get me going again without a lot of frustration.

[1] http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi

---

Originally posted by [covertbagel](https://answers.ros.org/users/13386/covertbagel/) with karma: 51 on 2015-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0